# Creating a function in R for vector/matrix data

Tags: r, function, matrix, vector

I have a folder with 1000+ files. I want to check files one by one, but I don't want to load those in R. What i did is create a matrix and in each row is one file path. By using the file path I can get what I want. So what I did up now.

I started to create a matrix:

```
path <- "/Users/mike/Desktop/folder"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.txt")
dt <- matrix(paste("/Users/mike/Desktop/folder", files, sep="/"))
```

dt is matrix, if I call first row and analyse it i get what I want:

```
a <- dt[1,]
analyse(a)
```

My question now is how to do this automatically for 100+ files? I think that I have to do a function, but problem is that I dont know how to do it.

Can someone give me a hand?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you have tried? We cannot do assignment for you... Show us where you are getting problem?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Im trying to create a automatically process to call different files in R for analyzing. So I started with this code: path <- "/Users/mike/Desktop/folder"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.txt")
datafile <- matrix(paste("/Users/mike/Desktop/folder", files, sep="/"))
a <- datafile[1,]
analyse(a)

right now i called the first row and works fine, but how i can call all row one by one automatically?

thank you

Comment: Add your logic to your question... It would be helpful to others...

Comment: thanks, updated all question, hope now is clear and useful for other members.

Comment: @user3872487.  You said you did `analyse(a)` without loading the dataset.  I couldn't understand the problem.

Comment: analyse(a) is only for first row which correspondent to first dataset, but how i can do this automatically for all datasets (rows) a <- dt[2,]; a <- dt[3,] etc...  a <- dt[1000,] 

analyse(a)

Comment: @user3872487. I couldn't find the function `analyse` and not sure what that does

Comment: @akrun Forget about `analyse` is just for example. The question is how to get automatically `a <- dt[2,]; a <- dt[3,] etc... a <- dt[1000,]` Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need your third line if you do it like this:

```
path <- "/Users/mike/Desktop/folder"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.txt", full.names =TRUE)
```

And you don't need  a matrix. You can simply write:

```
analysis <- list(NULL)
for(i in 1:length(files)){
   analysis[[i]] <- analyse(files[i])
}

analysis
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I did it but analyse only last file 

`for(file in files){
          i <-  analyse(file)
} 

i`

Comment: you have to store the result of your analysis properly (see edit)

Comment: i dont know but get analyse only for first file and repeat it 10 times. So is only first file analysed, not others. Thanks anyway for your effort.

Comment: Ah, sorry, see edit. That comes when there is no data to test.

Comment: your approach work well, thanks for this. But i get an `Warning messages:
          1: In analysis[i] <- analyse(files[i]) :
          number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` can you help on this?

Comment: So you seem to return not a single value but maybe an vector or array. If you make `analysis` a list you can store in it a vector or array or another list. Note the double square brackets. 
Next time when you ask something, give some information about the data structure of your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a simple 'for' loop:

```
mm = as.matrix(paste("file",1:10,".txt", sep=""))
mm
      [,1]        
 [1,] "file1.txt" 
 [2,] "file2.txt" 
 [3,] "file3.txt" 
 [4,] "file4.txt" 
 [5,] "file5.txt" 
 [6,] "file6.txt" 
 [7,] "file7.txt" 
 [8,] "file8.txt" 
 [9,] "file9.txt" 
[10,] "file10.txt"

for(i in 1:nrow(mm)) print(mm[i])
[1] "file1.txt"
[1] "file2.txt"
[1] "file3.txt"
[1] "file4.txt"
[1] "file5.txt"
[1] "file6.txt"
[1] "file7.txt"
[1] "file8.txt"
[1] "file9.txt"
[1] "file10.txt"

for(i in 1:nrow(mm)) {a = mm[i,]; analyze(a)}
```

Comment: thanks for code, `for(i in 1:nrow(mm)) print(mm[i])` show all files one by one, can i use this `analyse(mm[i])` tried but not work. If I do `analyse(mm[1])` will work. I know that need to customize that function but still don't know how.